# Why the process time increase as the trim position increases?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've been trimming some videos recently using ffmpeg, and I've noticed that as the trim position increases, the time taken to trim the video also increases.Even if the duration is same. `(5 seconds)`

[image]

Below given the command to trim the video from `0` to `5` seconds, and it takes only 1 second to process.

```
ffmpeg -y \
    -i input.mp4 \
    -filter_complex \
        "[0:v]trim=0:5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; 
     [0:a]atrim=0:5, asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0] 
" -map "[v0]" -map "[a0]" output.mp4
```

But when I try to trim the video with exact same command, but with different index, from `300` second to `305`, it takes `5 seconds`.

```
ffmpeg -y \
    -i input.mp4 \
    -filter_complex \
        "[0:v]trim=300:305,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0]; 
     [0:a]atrim=300:305, asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a0] 
" -map "[v0]" -map "[a0]" output.mp4
```

So here are my questions

1. Why the process time increase as the position increases?
2. Is there any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trimming the streams using filters, so all frames from the start of the file till the trim points still have to be decoded in order to be trimmed.

For MP4 files, perform an input seek, which will only pull frames from the closest keyframe. No need to use filters either since all trimming and timestamp reset happens via input switches.

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 300 -to 305 -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -map 0:a output.mp4
```

Comment: Actually, I have many filters using in the [real world scenario](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/teamxenox/auto-motion/master/lab/command.sh). That's why I use `filter_complex`. I tried the command you told. It works. Is there any possibility to run this command along with the `filter_complex` (in a single command).   Otherwise, I'd have to trim the video in a different command and concat it in the `filter_complex`. What do you suggest ?

Comment: Across all your trim filters, you're consuming the entire video stream as portions and then feeding them to concat after some filtering. This will take time  Instead of applying all the trims to 0:v, Ingest 0:v once and split it to 15 outputs and then filter those.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for your suggestion Gyan.